# MongoDB on Amazon SSD-backed EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, solid-state-drive

We have mongodb sharded cluster currently deployed on EC2 instances in Amazon. These shards are also replica sets. The instances used are using EBS with IOPS provisioned.

We have about 30 million documents in a collection. Our queries count the whole collection that matches the filters. We have indexes on almost all of the query-able fields. This results to the RAM reaching 100% usage. Our working set exceeds the size of the RAM. We think that the slow response of our queries are caused by EBS being slow so we are thinking of migrating to the new SSD-backed instances.

C3 is available
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/11/a-generation-of-ec2-instances-for-compute-intensive-workloads.html

I2 is coming soon
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/11/coming-soon-the-i2-instance-type-high-io-performance-via-ssd.html

Our only concern is that SSD is ephemeral, meaning the data will be gone once the instance stops, terminates, or fails. How can we address this? How do we automate backups. Is it a good idea to migrate to SSD to improve the performance of our queries? Do we still need to set-up a sharded cluster?

Comment: That's good to know, but what's the question?

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted the question. :)

Comment: 30 million docs on a sharded cluster? Are you sure that is needed? Are you sure your working set exceeds RAM? SSDs may help put your working set into RAM but if you are constantly reading from disk (due to working set not fitting) it won't be much help

Comment: Sharding definitely increased the performance of our queries but I'm not sure if we can afford increasing the number of shards. Yes my working set exceeds the RAM since we have indexes on all fields that are being queried. Reading from SSD vs reading from EBS I think has a great difference in performance that will improve our queries.

Comment: Hmm I do question how the SSD is actually physically connected to the virtual machine, if it is through a shared data reader, like on most cloud platforms then it won't help terribly, you may notice a speed up but you will suffer from other peoples IO needs (like the company I work for does on rackspace). Also even though a SSD is 150x faster than a normal disk it still isn't a silver bullet, you need to make a window whereby your data fits, have you calced how big your working set is?

Comment: Based on the link provided, SSD is local to the machine, so I guess it is physically connected.

Here is the dataSizes and indexSizes of the three shards
shard1
"dataSize" : 20011448940
"indexSize" : 9980802944

shard2
"dataSize" : 7491326872
"indexSize" : 10213393792

shard3
"dataSize" : 8177792632
"indexSize" : 11054205456

Comment: Can you graph a 10 min window of workingSet: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-workingset ? That will tell you what you actually need in terms of RAM, data size isn't important here

Comment: Though about instance stopping, you can put on termination protection which should prevent it from being randomly downed. Also you should look into MMS backups

Comment: hmm, bad schema design? ^^

Comment: Our queries require that all data that has to be processed must be stored in a single collection.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the ephemeral disks is a risk but if you have your replication setup correctly it  shouldn't be a huge concern.  I'm assuming you've setup a three node replica set correct?  Also you have three nodes for your config servers?

I can speak of this from experience as the company I'm at has been setup this way.  To help mitigate risk I'm moving towards a backup strategy that involved a hidden replica.  With this setup I can shutdown the hidden replica set and one of the config servers (first having stopped balancing) and take a complete copy of the data files (replica and config server) and have a valid backup.  If AWS went down on my availability zone I'd still have a daily backup available on S3 to restore from.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is replication more effective that MMS backups?

Comment: Not sure as we have not engaged MMS.  The costs are quite prohibitive for us.

Comment: Please excuse the necro-post. You should try to avoid conflating Backup (recovery) with Replication (durability) as they have different purposes.